# Did E.E. Cummings say "I never saw a pessimistic general win a battle"?

Tags: quotes

Where does the quote "I never saw a pessimistic general win a battle" come from?

I saw it posted on Facebook and attributed to American poet, [E.E. Cummings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._E._Cummings) (or e. e. cummings, as he [sometimes liked to style it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._E._Cummings#Name_and_capitalization)).

I'm not a poetry expert, but from what I remember of him, it didn't sound like something he would say.  I googled just the quote and it appears that Eisenhower said it.  However, if you google the quote plus "E.E. Cummings" you get multiple hits attributing the quote to him.

The friend who posted it even posted a picture of the quote in a book attributing it to Cummings.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 1974 book [Your Handicap: Don't Let It Handicap You](https://books.google.com/books?id=nS7borem8a4C&q=%22pessimistic%20general%20win%22&dq=%22pessimistic%20general%20win%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ4M-N0pLTAhWIZiYKHeDZBokQ6AEIHjAB) says:

> At a meeting of the Board of Trustees of [People-to-People](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People_to_People_Student_Ambassador_Program) in September, 1965, former President Dwight D. Eisenhower said, "I never saw a pessimistic general win a battle."

Furthermore, a US government archive document [EISENHOWER, DWIGHT D.: POST-PRESIDENTIAL PAPERS, 1961-69: 1965 PRINCIPAL FILE](https://www.eisenhower.archives.gov/research/finding_aids/pdf/Eisenhower_Dwight_Post_Presidential_Papers/1965_Principal_File.pdf) says:

> WAS (1)-(3) [Abbott Washburn-People-to-People; Eisenhower quote, “I never saw a
>   pessimistic General win a battle;” Eisenhower comments on People-to-People’s
>   origins and reasons for supporting it; C. Langhorne Washburn-Republican National
>   Committee; items stolen from Eisenhower’s car]

These references are specific as to time and place, and seem to credibly support that Eisenhower did use the quote. Yet, it's still a possibility that the quote was used by E. E. Cummings (who died in 1962) first.

Comment: The two quotes do support that Eisenhower used that line on at least two occasions. But this still doesn't rule out that it was Cummings who coined it after all. Cummings died in 1962, three years before the given dates. Eisenhower could simply be quoting Cummings himself (knowingly or unknowingly). I don't claim that this is what must have happened. Yet it seems to me that it may be rather difficult to prove that the quote indeed was first used by Eisenhower and not Cummings by producing evidence that Eisenhower used it at some point.

Comment: @Schmuddi yes, I can't rule out that Cummings said it too

Comment: I've edited your conclusion to include that possibility. What do you think?

Comment: @Schmuddi ok, I approved the edit